Automatically assign nrow and ncol in ggarrange
I have a of list of 5 plots and using ggarrange to lay them out in matrix of 2x2 for the first 4 plots the results comes out fine but last plot arrange is showing 1 plot on the 2x2 matrix because of which empty space is created between the x axis and the plot.
Searching in Google and stack overflow. Expecting an answer.

What you can do is first, arrange the first four plots in a 2x2 grid.
Then, combine this 2x2 grid with the fifth plot, placing it below.
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(cowplot)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, qsec)) + geom_point()
p3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, drat)) + geom_point()
p4 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) + geom_point()
p5 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point()

# Arrange the first four plots in a 2x2 grid
top_grid <- ggarrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)

# Combine the top grid with the fifth plot below
final_plot <- plot_grid(top_grid, p5, ncol = 1, rel_heights = c(2, 1))

# Display the combined plot
print(final_plot)


Thank you! The workaround is good but the problem is that I have multiple plots in a list coming from a loop which could be any number. So someone I need ggarrange automatically decide example, 4 plots in page1, 4 plots in page 2, then say 2 plots in page 3?
